# Find neighbours in a pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset of bicycles where I have columns for the store, where they are sold, and some information on the bicycle model. **I need to compare the sales numbers of models in each store**. For that reason I need to do the following:

- Group bicycles by store:

  `groups = df.groupby('store_id')`
- Then, for each model in that store, I need to find models that have similar characteristics. That is similar height, length, weight, etc. For that, I have set a 10% difference bound, meaning if the difference in weight between the two models is less than 10%, the other model is a comparable neighbor.
- Finally, for each model, I want to see where it ranks among its competitors, giving it a "top seller" label if it performs better than 50% of them.

The problem is, **I don't know how to do steps 2 and 3**. Does anybody have an idea? I've taken a look at Groupby.Transform in the pandas documentation, but I don't know how it fits in the whole picture.

Your help would be really appreciated!

Comment: How would you like your output from step 2 to be organised? it seems that you will have nC2 results for pair-wise comparison of n models.

Comment: The result from step 2 would be a series with a list of neighbors in each row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def sales_rank(x, df):
    df_ns = df.set_index('id')
    df_ns = df_ns.loc[x.neighbors, 'sales']
    df_ns.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
    df_ns = df_ns.reset_index()
    return df_ns[df_ns.id == x.id].index[0]


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': range(5), 'weight': [20, 21, 23, 43, 22], 'sales':[200, 100, 140, 100, 100]})
df['neighbors'] = df.weight.apply(lambda x: df.id[np.isclose(df.weight.values, x, rtol=0.10)].values)
df['sales_rank_in_neighborhood'] = df.apply(lambda x: sales_rank(x, df) , axis=1)
df['top_seller'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.sales_rank_in_neighborhood < len(x.neighbors)//2, axis=1)
print(df)
```

#### Output

```
   id  weight  sales     neighbors  sales_rank_in_neighborhood  top_seller
0   0      20    200     [0, 1, 4]                           0        True
1   1      21    100  [0, 1, 2, 4]                           3       False
2   2      23    140     [1, 2, 4]                           0        True
3   3      43    100           [3]                           0       False
4   4      22    100  [0, 1, 2, 4]                           2       False
```

Note that there are no top sellers in single-element neighborhoods. Tweak the rule to suit your purposes.

I hope this helps!

### Edits

I added a solution for groups, multiple rules for defining neighborhood and fixed sales rank implementation:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def ns(x, df):
    weight_rule = np.isclose(df.weight.values, x.weight, rtol=0.10)
    gear_rule = df.gear == x.gear
    type_rule = df.type == x.type
    return df.id[np.logical_and.reduce((weight_rule, gear_rule, type_rule))].values


def sales_rank(x, df):
    df_ns = df.set_index('id')
    df_ns = df_ns.loc[x.neighbors, 'sales']
    df_ns.sort_values(ascending=False, inplace=True)
    df_ns = df_ns.reset_index()
    return df_ns[df_ns.id == x.id].index[0]


df = pd.DataFrame(data={'store_id': [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'id': range(5), 'weight': [20, 21, 23, 43, 22], 'gear': [3, 3, 3, 7, 3], 'type':['mountain', 'mountain', 'mountain', 'bmx', 'mountain'], 'sales':[200, 100, 140, 100, 100]})
# Columns for results
df['neighbors'] = ''
df['sales_rank_in_neighborhood'] = ''
df['top_seller'] = ''
groups = df.groupby('store_id')

for _, g in groups:
    df_temp = df.loc[g.index, :]
    df_temp.neighbors = df_temp.apply(lambda x: ns(x, df_temp), axis=1)
    df_temp.sales_rank_in_neighborhood = df_temp.apply(lambda x: sales_rank(x, df_temp), axis=1)
    df_temp.top_seller = df_temp.apply(lambda x: x.sales_rank_in_neighborhood < len(x.neighbors)//2, axis=1)
    df.loc[g.index, :] = df_temp

print(df)
```

#### Output

```
   store_id  id  weight  gear      type  sales  neighbors sales_rank_in_neighborhood top_seller
0         0   0      20     3  mountain    200     [0, 4]                          0       True
1         1   1      21     3  mountain    100        [1]                          0      False
2         0   2      23     3  mountain    140     [2, 4]                          0       True
3         1   3      43     7       bmx    100        [3]                          0      False
4         0   4      22     3  mountain    100  [0, 2, 4]                          2      False
```

I guess there would be a way for avoiding looping over groups but this seems to do the trick.

Comment: The thing is, i have to find neighbours based on several characteristics, not just weight. For some of them, the neighbourhood bound is percentual and for some other properties it's a raw value (number of gears). Do you know a way to solve this?

Comment: I took a look at the solution, but the sales rank only shows the position of the index in the list, which is arbitrary. Do you know how to sort it before? Thanks

Comment: I edited my answer to include multiple rules for neighborhood. I started to wonder whether you'd like to cluster the data instead of finding rule-based neighbors for each data point?

Comment: I'll fix the sales rank implementation. Don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Fixed sales rank implementation.